# How to uncheck all radios in a RadioButtonList on the client-side and persist after postback

Tags: webforms

There is a bug with the ASP .NET Web Forms RadioButtonList - if you uncheck all the radios on the client-side (with javascript), after you do a postback the first item in the list will be selected.

For example, try running the following jquery:

```
$('#myRadioList input').attr('checked', '');
```

After you do a postback, the first item in the RadioButtonList will be selected.

Anyone know an elegant work around?

Answer (score 0):

It's because by design you will need to choose one option

To uncheck all:

```
 $('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', false);
```

place it to the end of the page or inside

a `$(function() {});` or `$(document).ready(function() {});` block

**P.S.** Use `prop` instead of `attr` if jQuery 1.6+

> [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: I know how to do it using JQuery (I showed how to do it in my questions even) - the problem is that it doesn't persist when you post back!

Comment: are you populating your lists only inside `if(!Page.IsPostBack)` event, or every time you load that page?

Comment: The list is populated declaratively (i.e. in the aspx, not the codebehind).